# Are implicitly imported Maven BOM files dominant in Gradle?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, maven-bom

I develop a Spring Boot 2.0.x application which uses Gradle 5.2.1 to import multiple Maven BOMs, both custom and official Spring BOMs. Therefore, I use the `platform` syntax provided by Gradle. However, I use the `dependency-management` plugin in combination with the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin, too.

```
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {
    compile platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}")
    compile platform("com.myOrg:custom-bom:${latestVersion}")
}
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/) this combination of plugins triggers the inclusion of the Spring Boot BOM file. However, I do not know how this implicitly included BOM fits into the regular order of BOMs. Is it applied first and thus can be overridden by other BOMs or is it applied last and thus dominates all other BOM files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Gradle world with only `platform` usage for BOMs, there is no precedence rule. Gradle will consider *all* constraints brought in by the different BOMs *and transitive dependencies* and conflict resolve them in the usual fashion if they recommend different versions.

I am not a specialist of the Spring `dependency-management` plugin, but my understanding is that it aims at replicating the Maven BOM contract: versions of the BOM overrule any transitive version and can in turn be overruled by local version declarations.

If that understanding is correct, then the `dependency-management` plugin will apply its rules for all dependencies that are covered by the BOMs it imports. Anything not covered by the plugin will obey the Gradle rules.

In that sense, the mix might not be an ideal situation, as changes in BOM content over version in either direction could have pretty serious impact on resolved dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I have experimented with different combinations of the usage of the plugin and BOMs and your assumptions seem to be correct. Furthermore, I found out that I received a similar result when I use `enforcePlatform` to include the Spring Boot BOM without the need for the plugin.

Comment: @RobinEllerkmann thanks for comment about enforcePlatform, realy help me